# Automatically Logging Exceptions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, logging, exception

Is there a library or easy way to catch exceptions thrown in a Ruby program and log it to a file? I've looked over [log4r](http://log4r.sourceforge.net/) and [logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html), but the docs on both don't provide any examples on how I would do this. I run this program remotely and lose handles to stdout and stderr, if that information helps at all.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to take a walk on the wild side, try this:

```
class Exception
  alias real_init initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    real_init *args
    # log the error (self) or its args here
  end
end
```

This will intercept the creation of new exception objects at the moment of creation.

Comment: This 'works', but appears to break Rails 4.x startup (autoloading?) in some way.

Answer (score 5):

Rescue from `Exception`. Something like this probably makes sense:

```
begin
  # run your code here ..
rescue Exception => exception
  # logger.error(...) ....
  raise exception
end
```

This will log the exception, and re-raise it so that the application actually raises an error in addition to the logging.

`exception` is an instance of `Exception`, take a look at [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Exception.html) for information about what you can do with this object (such as accessing the backtrace).

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of having to do. The code involved is basically one class with a number of methods in it; would I just have to put a begin / rescue on every method or is there an easier way?

Comment: You're probably creating instances somewhere -- put the rescue block where you create the instances.

Comment: Putting it on the instance creation code won't do any good unless the error is in the creation.  If you're wanting to catch any errors, globally, wrap your main body.

Comment: I'm not talking about putting it in the "initialize" method, but the part of the code where you call ".new".

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems like that would work also. I'm a little concerned that I'd have to do that everywhere I interact with this class (since it's done over the network) and that monkeypatching, although a bit sketchy, gets the job done well enough. +1 for the help though and thanks again!

Comment: Within a `rescue` block you can simply write `raise`, AFAIK it's the idiomatic way to re-raise an exception that you just caught.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a Rails app, the [Exception Notification](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/master) plugin is very handy.

Comment: Ah yes, I've definitely seen it, but my app in question isn't a Rails app. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if I did something like this:

```
begin
  main()
rescue Exception => e
  myCustomErrorLogger(e)
end

def main()
  # All the application code comes here.
end
```

What I need is to have all my uncaught exceptions move to the top-most level, and be caught there and subsequently recorded by the error logging function.

I'm trying this out now, but it would be great to have your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the code of the class Exception in the part that puts to stdout the reason and the backtrace.

Don't forget to check if the logger can be null, the exception can be throwed before (or while) the logger its created.